# Changing navbar height for mobile device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create a 100px fixed navbar. Therefore I have changed the css style:

```
 .navbar { height: 100px }
```

and

```
.navbar-inner { height: 100px }
```

But as soon as I click on the menu button in < 768px size for mobile devices, the menu starts at 50px again. It works fine on full size. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: can you write your source code ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, bootstrap (at least v3) does not force the height. The style on .navbar is min-height: 50px which means if you specified height: 100px, you should always get 100px. There is probably some custom rules elsewhere overwriting your styles. Since it only happens on the xs view the styles are probably in a @media (max-width: 767px) style. The best option is to use firebug (or chrome's knock off) and find the code setting it to 50px and delete it.

Alternatively you can try adding an important flag but again, less style is more so try to delete the other code first:

```
.navbar, .navbar-inner { height: 100px !important }
```